# paramiko uses 100 CPU and speed degrades if multiple paramiko scripts executed at same time

Tags: python, paramiko

The following code is working perfectly and downloading 6GB file in 7mins. and also 10 such scripts downloading 10*6-60 gb in 7 mins. my PC supports 16 core and when i try to run  30 paramiko python scripts at same time the downloading takes hours and hours as because cores fully engaged. each paramiko python script using 100% CPU.
i am using paramiko window size also for good spped. i know i have to use time.sleep in my python script.. but how to use this i have done multiple time using sleep but failed please suggest how to make paramiko uses less cpu.
the code is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys, paramiko
hostname = 'x.x.85.y8'
password = 'XXXX1234'
source = r'/root/1/kerneljobs/28.tar'
dest = r"/root/1/kerneljobs/destuny.tar"
username = "root"
port = 22
try:
    t = paramiko.Transport((hostname, port))
    t.connect(username=username, password=password)
    sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(t)
    sftp.get(source, dest)
finally:
    t.close()
```

Comment: *"i know i have to use time.sleep"* - Why should sleep help? + Why do you even run 30 scripts in parallel?

Comment: i am not sure about sleep but that is what i understood from browsing.. 30 scripts from 30 host 6gB file each to get in different locations on same machine

Comment: is there any single paramiko script for 30 hosts which takes donwload parallely

Comment: 30 parallel downloads can hardly work nicely. You still didn’t explain why you need that.

Comment: but its working nicely for 13 parallel downloads... i need to download 30 inorder save time after that i will keep wait.. so for every 30 i will put wait in bash and i have to download 500 such files to process data.. processing data i can manage as i have 132 GB RAM with 16 processosrs

Comment: Using 30 connections won’t save you any time.

Comment: yes.. thanksyou.. just now i realized that even filezilla client also based on max process its keeping other files in to queue,, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

It makes no sense to open

- more than about 3-4 connections, if network latency is bottleneck or
- more connections than CPU cores, if CPU is bottleneck.